# Transpose Inconsistent data set from columns to rows csv or excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv, transpose

Hi there I have a csv file with about 380k rows and tree columns.
column A - I have the key, it is repeating for each trim version and every trim version starts every time with the word Brand
column B - the specification
column C - trim ID, its the same number for every trim version

My problem is that I have inconsisent data range, some trim version has up to 55 rows of data, and others just 5-6

```
(A)KEY                              (B)VALUE            (C)TRIM ID
======                              ========            ==========
1. Brand                            Mitsubishi          20001
2. Model                            ASX                 20001
3. Trim                             ASX (facelift 2012) 20001
4. Engine                           1.8 DI-D (114 Hp)   20001
5. Doors                            5                   20001
6. Power                            114 hp              20001
7. Maximum speed                    189 km/h            20001
8. From 0 to 100 km/h               10.2 sec            20001
9. Fuel tank volume                 63 l                20001
10. Year into production            2012                20001
11. Seats                           5                   20001                       
1. Brand                            BMW                 20015
2. Model                            M4                  20015
3. Trim                             M4 (F83)            20015
4. Engine                           3.0 (431 Hp) DCT    20015
5. Power                            431 hp              20015
1. Brand                            AUDI                25003
2. Model                            A4                  25003
3. Trim                             1.9TDI AVANT SLINE  25003
4. Power                            131 hp              25003
```

I want to transpose the data to ONE ROW PER TRIM VERSION and match the data. For example each time the Brand is found startst new row with data and the rest of the data is matched to to column name Brand, model... seats etc..

Like this:

```
Brand   Model   Generation  Engine  Doors   Power   Maximum speed   Seats   Length
=====   =====    =========   =====  =====   =====   =============   =====   ======
AUDI    A4      2.0T SLINE  2.0T    5       210     220             4         4520
BMW     M3                  330                     280             4
HONDA   CIVIC               1.6i    4       160                     4
```

I was trying to solve this problem with functions but I think I need vba script and I am not good at that. Please Help me.

Comment: Where do you put the TRIM ID (Col C) in the new data?

Comment: I dont need he TRIM ID in the new data set. Maybe I should mention that later the csv data will be converted in to DB for a website.

Comment: Perfect! Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with this I did (and with the data sample you provide)

```
Sub createDataTable()
    Dim r
    Dim c
    Dim i
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newSht As Worksheet
    Dim dataSht As Worksheet
    Dim j 'the counter for the rows of the table
    Dim colName As Range
    Dim theAddress

    Set dataSht = Sheets("Data")
    dataSht.Activate
    r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'take the last row of the data
    c = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column 'Take the last columns of the data
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(r, 1)) 'Store the column 1=A of the data

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add a new sheet
    Set newSht = ActiveSheet 'Store the new sheet int the var
    newSht.Name = myTime 'Rename the new sheet with the function
    j = 1

    dataSht.Activate
    rng.Copy
    Range("H1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveSheet.Range("$H:$H").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    Range("H1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
    newSht.Activate
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True

    dataSht.Activate 'Go to the new sheet (just in case)
    Range("H1", Selection.End(xlDown)).ClearContents

    For Each i In rng 'Here comes the magic
        If i.Value = "Brand" Then 'If is a Brand set a new row
            j = j + 1
        End If
        newSht.Activate 'Lets go to the new sheet
        With newSht.Range("A1:BZ1") 'With the headers...
            Set colName = .Find(i.Value, LookIn:=xlValues) '...Find the header of the column in that range
            If Not colName Is Nothing Then 'If colName has something then
                theAddress = colName.Address 'Put the address of the address just for reference
                Do 'and inner loop
                    Range(Cells(j, colName.Column), Cells(j, colName.Column)).Value = i.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    'put the value of the field inside the cell below the right header in the right row
                    'col header = colName.column
                    'right row = j
                    'Set colName = .FindNext(colName) 'this is not necesary, because the header are unique
                Loop While Not colName Is Nothing And colName.Address <> theAddress
            End If
        End With
        dataSht.Activate
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit #1**

This code creates the headers

```
Sub createDataTable()
    Dim r
    Dim c
    Dim i
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newSht As Worksheet
    Dim dataSht As Worksheet
    Dim j 'the counter for the rows of the table
    Dim colName As Range
    Dim theAddress

    Set dataSht = Sheets("Data")
    dataSht.Activate
    'to create headers
    Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Key"
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "Value"
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Trim"
    Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True

    r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'take the last row of the data
    c = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column 'Take the last columns of the data
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(r, 1)) 'Store the column 1=A of the data

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Add a new sheet
    Set newSht = ActiveSheet 'Store the new sheet int the var
    newSht.Name = myTime 'Rename the new sheet with the function
    j = 1

    dataSht.Activate
    rng.Copy
    Range("H1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveSheet.Range("$H:$H").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    Range("H1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
    newSht.Activate
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True

    dataSht.Activate 'Go to the new sheet (just in case)
    Range("H1", Selection.End(xlDown)).ClearContents

    For Each i In rng 'Here comes the magic
        If i.Value = "Brand" Then 'If is a Brand set a new row
            j = j + 1
        End If
        newSht.Activate 'Lets go to the new sheet
        With newSht.Range("A1:BZ1") 'With the headers...
            Set colName = .Find(i.Value, LookIn:=xlValues) '...Find the header of the column in that range
            If Not colName Is Nothing Then 'If colName has something then
                theAddress = colName.Address 'Put the address of the address just for reference
                Do 'and inner loop
                    Range(Cells(j, colName.Column), Cells(j, colName.Column)).Value = i.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    'put the value of the field inside the cell below the right header in the right row
                    'col header = colName.column
                    'right row = j
                    'Set colName = .FindNext(colName) 'this is not necesary, because the header are unique
                Loop While Not colName Is Nothing And colName.Address <> theAddress
            End If
        End With
        dataSht.Activate
    Next i
End Sub
```

And as I can see in the screenshots, you put the code inside the worksheet, that will return a error 1004

[image]

Because you can't "manipulate" another sheet from a sheet. If you need/want to do that, you need to do it inside a module, and then call the procedure from that module.

In this case, you need to add a new module
With the workbook selected in the VBA

```
Insert >>> Module
```

and a new module will be in you proyect, and add the procedure from **Edit #2** inside that module, then run it, with `F5`.

Let me know if you need an improvement.

**Edit #2**

I'm glad that help you... and the error that you have is because I did send you the custom function... Sorry... Here goes!

```
Function myTime() As String
    Dim HH
    Dim MM
    Dim SS
    Dim TT
    HH = Hour(Now)
    MM = Minute(Now)
    SS = Second(Now)
    myTime = Format(HH, "00") & Format(MM, "00") & Format(SS, "00")
End Function
```

Put this function in the same module that you put all the code.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I get an error - Run-time error '9' , Subscript out of range

Comment: Can you share screenshots of the data, and the error?? And the data is store from A1 to right and down???

Comment: You can see the sceenshot of the data here [dataset](http://snag.gy/JxOSc.jpg) ---- And this is the error I get [error](http://snag.gy/6qdb5.jpg).

Comment: Your data has no headers!!! That is why you get the error. Always provide a real info about the data.

Comment: Please check the **Edit #2**

Comment: Thank you ElbertV, **the code works perfectly** after removing this line `newSht.Name = myTime 'Rename the new sheet with the function`, becasue it gave me error in the debug.

Comment: Ok, Please check my edit #2, to see the custom function `mytime`. Sorry I did not put it before in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be easily accomplished  with a pivot table. Just import your csv data into excel and convert it into a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question becasue I found a prefect and powerful solution to this problem that is called OpenRefine, a former google project (Google Refine).

As my data sets are over a millioon rows now, this is the fastest and best solution (much better than excel) to work with.

http://openrefine.org/